# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - "site can’t provide a secure connection" when setting application url using .UseUrls()

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I'm running the app using "dotnet run". If I don't set the url programmatically using .UseUrls() then it picks it up from launchSettings.json and all good. However if I set THE SAME url using .UseUrls() I get the message below on the brower.

[image]

There are no errors from the code i.e. both cases report " Now listening on: http://localhost:6001". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **Strict-Transport-Security** from your *Web.config*

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" 

        value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Good to know thanks - noted for any future problems.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake - launchSettings.json was using https://localhost:6001 and the code was using http://localhost:6001. Doh!